# Creating NSTextFields programmatically in Swift

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6, nstextfield

Is there any way to create NSTextFields completely programmatically using Swift? I am creating a mac application that I would rather not connect to a storyboard, but I can't figure out any method of creating NSTextFields besides making an IBOutlet. By the way, I'm new to programming, so sorry for my lack of technical language.

Thank You!

Edit:

Here's the code that I have tried so far:

When I do this, I get the error message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value." The same error message pops up whether I make test an SKView or an NSView. If I try defining the IBOutlet as "view" instead of "test", it tells me that I can't override the stored property "view".

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit

class SettingsScene: SKScene {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var test: SKView!

    var ballSpeedText = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(20,20,200,40))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        ballSpeedText.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
        ballSpeedText.stringValue = "Test"
        test.addSubview(ballSpeedText)
    }
```

If I try doing it without creating any IBOutlets, just using view, I don't get any errors, but the text field does not show up:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit

class SettingsScene: SKScene {

    var ballSpeedText = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(20,20,200,40))

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        ballSpeedText.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
        ballSpeedText.stringValue = "Test"
        view.addSubview(ballSpeedText)
    }
```

Comment: You have to use SKLabel with SpriteKit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it easily. Just connect your view to an outlet, then you can do like this:

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    private var window: NSWindow?

    let textField = NSTextField(frame: .init(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 40))

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSScreen.main?.frame ?? .zero,
        styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled],
        backing: .buffered,
        defer: false)
        window?.title = "My App"
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        textField.textColor = .red
        textField.stringValue = "Hello World !!!"
        window?.contentView?.addSubview(textField)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Add a `main.swift` file to your project:

```
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

And in your target deployment info, remove the main.storyboard from the Main Interface:

[image]

Comment: I probably should have clarified that I am making a game using SpriteKit. I have a class that inherits from SKScene in which I am trying to display the NSTextField. Since it inherits from SKScene, it already has a view property, but when I do `view.addSubview(myTextField)`, it doesn't work. I also get an error when I attempt to define an IBOutlet with the name "view." Is there any way to do this in my class? Thanks!

Comment: SKView inherits from NSView. The View property of SKScene is SKView I believe